# Is there a URL that can be used for a "Share on Slack" button?

Tags: social-sharing-buttons

I'd like to put a "Share on Slack" button on my website.   It would be similar to the buttons we have for "Share on Facebook" and "Share on Twitter".  A user would click on it and be able to post some text and a link that we suggest on Slack.

I've been able to find URLs that I can use on Facebook and Twitter for doing this, but I've been unable to track down one for Slack?  Does it exist?   I see that [AddThis was able to implement a button](http://www.addthis.com/social-buttons/slack-button) but I'm not sure exactly how they are doing it.